# Devoloping amazon WS-client using the product API in java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, api, web-services

I am developing an Amazon webservice client in java. I have developed all the stubs needed as specified in their site. I could access the title and asin using ItemLookup response. I need to access the price information and image of products. Can someone help me to sort the issue.The code and its response is given below

```
public class iteml {
   public void itemdetails()
   {
    System.out.println("sample test");
    AWSECommerceService service = new AWSECommerceService();
    service.setHandlerResolver(new awshandlerresolver("secret key"));  // important
    AWSECommerceServicePortType port = service.getAWSECommerceServicePort();

ItemLookupRequest itemLookup = new ItemLookupRequest();
itemLookup.setIdType("ASIN");
itemLookup.getItemId().add("B0036WT3EI");

ItemLookup lookup = new ItemLookup();
lookup.setAWSAccessKeyId("APi key"); // important
lookup.getRequest().add(itemLookup);

ItemLookupResponse response = port.itemLookup(lookup);

String r = response.toString();
System.out.println("response: " + r);


      for (Items itemList:response.getItems())

        for (Item item : itemList.getItem())
        {
           final String asin= item.getASIN();
            System.out.println(asin);
            System.out.println("Title: " +
            item.getItemAttributes().getTitle());
           // Image I=item.getSmallImage();
             // final Image I1 = I;
           // String url=I1.getURL();
           // System.out.println(url);

            String pr=item.getItemAttributes().getListPrice().getFormattedPrice();
           // System.out.println(p);
            System.out.println(pr);
}
}


public static void main(String args[])
    {
      iteml l=new iteml();
      l.itemdetails();
    }
  }
```

> **output is** B0036WT3EI  //asin id
>   Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.NullPointerException Title:
>   Samsung LN19C350 19-Inch 720p 60 Hz
>   LCD HDTV (Black)
>           at plugin.iteml.itemdetails(iteml.java:65)
>           at plugin.iteml.main(iteml.java:73) Java
>   Result: 1

Answer (score 2):

I am afraid to be a bit late, but here we go.

After this piece of code:

```
ItemLookupRequest itemLookup = new ItemLookupRequest();
itemLookup.setIdType("ASIN");
itemLookup.getItemId().add("B0036WT3EI");
```

add the following line:

```
itemLookup.setResponseGroup(new String[] { "Images", "ItemAttributes" });
```

You need to say that you want the `ItemLookupRequest` request to return a response with both Images and ItemAttributes (from where you extract the ListPrice).

I didn't test in Java, but should work fine.